# Como deletar uma coluna de várias tabelas no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma base de dados com mais de 100 tabelas, e gostaria de encontrar alguma forma de deletar uma coluna em especifico que todas as tabelas possuem em comum.
Existe alguma forma? Se sim, como?

Tentei executar o seguinte trecho, mas não funcionou:

```
ALTER TABLE 
(SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'nome_database' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "usuario" ORDER BY table_name) DROP COLUMN id_usuario;
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil escrever um pequeno programa, ou script, com 100 comandos? Claro, a pergunta por si só é válida, como curiosidade.

Comment: @epx eu pensei a mesma coisa, pois parece ser uma tarefa que seria feita apenas 1x. Depois nunca mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `mysql`, a tabela "information_schema.columns" tem o registro de todas as colunas em todas as tabelas, se fizer um select assim vai encontrar os nomes das tabelas:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE column_name = 'id_usuario';
```

Se quiser excluir as colunas das tabelas a partir dai precisa fazer duas coisas:

- Criar um [`CURSOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) para interar sobre cada resultado do `SELECT`;
- Montar e executar uma query dinâmica, mudando o nome da tabela para cada resultado do cursor. Para isso, pode usar os comandos `PREPARE` e `EXECUTE`, pode ler mais aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Não tenho agora como montar um exemplo funcional agora, mas pode criar uma procedure com o código nessa estrutura abaixo pra fazer esses passos:

```
DECLARE nome_tabela VARCHAR(500);

DECLARE cursor_tabelas CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'id_usuario';

OPEN cursor_tabelas;

LOOP
    FETCH cursor_tabelas INTO nome_tabela;
    
    SET @drop_command = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',nome_tabela,' DROP COLUMN id_usuario');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @drop_command;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    SELECT nome_tabela;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cursor_tabelas;
```